# How to avoid blaming a single person for issues submitting a group assignment?

Tags: conflict-aversion, politeness, approach, school, professionalism

I have a group assignment that is due soon. We are only allowed one submission per group (and further submissions, even before the deadline, will be penalized). This group assignment is worth a significant portion of our grade (about 50%).

This group assignment requires digitally submitting multiple separate documents and have very specific requirements (filename must be `groupAssignment1.pdf`, it must be submitted between 18:00 and 18:30 on a specific day, and so on). All group members receive the same grade.

**How can I/we submit the group assignment without putting the blame on the submitter for forgetting to submit a required document or submitting it "incorrectly" (as defined by the strict requirements)?**

At best, the blame should be put on the whole group if the submission was done "incorrectly".

I have suggested this:

> To meet up just before the deadline with everyone watching the submission process (one person prepares documents to submit, everyone else watches and catches errors). The people who did not/can not make it there have no right to complain if it was done incorrectly (I don't feel comfortable with this because some people have legitimate reasons for not  being able to make it).

Comment: Can you please add information about your cultural context? Answers may differ widely depending on where you live and what the cultural norm in your country is. European and North Americal cultures tend to blame individual people more than for example Japanese and other Asian cultures. That may also explain the *very dubious* requirements for submitting the documents.

Comment: You say you've already suggested a particular approach. What was the reaction to it? Or why do you think that approach is insufficient?

Comment: I don't know the cultural context you're dealing with, but in my classes in the US midwest, group assignments were judged to be the work of the group, not just whomever turned them in. The students had no ability to change that. That's what "all group members receive the same grade" is about.

Answer (score 2):

Do a peer review. Let person1 give their files for checking to person2. Person2 gives it to person3 and so on. Before the peer review, the group leader informs everyone of the rules and consequences. Once everyone is satisfied with the files, the leader submits it. You don't even have to meet. It can be done online.

Btw, a reality of all group projects is that only one or two members will do most of the work.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/258124487_The_problem_of_free-riding_in_group_projects_Looking_beyond_social_loafing_as_reason_for_non-contribution

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to IPS! It's a good idea,and it would be nice to add some background to this answer, IPS likes (and expects) answers to be backed up with experience/data/facts/studies. Thanks, and hope you'll have a great time around here :)